# For a same sql query, database takes different time to return the reponse

Tags: mysql

Below I executed a same select query five times (one after the other) and for each request the database takes different time to return the response. How cold that be possible?

- Request to Database -- took 10 ms.
- Request to Database -- took 6ms.
- Request to Database -- took 12 ms
- Request to Database -- took6 ms
- Request to Database -- took 9 ms

Thanks
Shashidhar

Comment: The computer and/or mysql server had different level of other things to do with you tried to run the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see the data. The minimum time needed was 50% of the maximum time needed. Generally, if the minimum is 80% of the maximum, then the needed time is considered to be fairly stable. If it is 40% or more, but less than 80%, then there is a moderate variance in needed time. If it is below 40%, then it can be considered volatile. Your needed time has a variance, but it is not volatile yet.

The cause of this variance depends on the tasks the server has to do while running your query. If there are a lot of requests to the database server, then, due to the increased concurrency the needed time is increased. Also, if data is varied (a lot of insertions and deletions occur in any short period of time), then selection's speed might increase or decrease, depending on the number of rows the table has and the number of rows matching the where criteria. If the table structure is varied (for instance an index is added or removed often), that may vary the performance of your operation as well. Last, but not least, if you did not actually check that the query being executed was the same each time, then there are chances that there were differences, especially if the query was generated dynamically.

So, the things you have observed are not strange, but whole minutes needed for a query to be executed seems to be a lot of time and maybe you should think about optimizing things.

Comment: I have a followup question over here. If a response time changes every time for a same set of data then what is a best way to verify a query performance?

Comment: @Sashi, first you need to count how many times you did the measure (to see how solid your pattern is) and calculate the average, to see what is the time you might expect from the next execution. Then, look at the number of records, the complexity of the relation you work with (how many tables and how big they are in record number and column number) and the complexity of your filter as well. Look at the attribute(s) of the computer(s) you work with and compare the performance to other performances you have seen.

Comment: Thanks Lajos. It was helpful.

Comment: I am glad I could help you.